# Is there any function to get form value in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, react-final-form

please help to understand the api document of react-final-form,

we have migrate redux-form to the react-final-form. in my application we are using formvalueselector api to get the form value. please help to get the slimier api in react-final-form

https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/

Requirement is get the form value by attribute name

Answer (score 6):

Try doing this via hook:

```
import { useFormState } from 'react-final-form';
...
const formState = useFormState();
let value = formState.values['attr_name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the form values from the render props of final-form.

```
<Form>
  {(values) => {
     const value = values['field-name'];
     ...
  }}
</Form>
```

If you like to get form values within a child component of your form use

```
import { useFormState } from 'react-final-form';

const ChildComponentOfForm = () => {
   const { values } = useFormState();
   const value = values['field-name'];

   ...
}
```